# How to get parent site name from subsite using Umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

Suggest how to get parent site name from subsite name from another root using umbraco.

For eg.
1) Home
   1.a) Overview
2) About

Assume that from search page i need to get name of the subsite name and parent site name like below:

1. Subsite1 - Home
2. Overview - Home
3. Subsite1 - Parent2
4. Subsite2 - Parent4

What i have tried:

```html
<pre>
@foreach( var container in Model.Content.Children("container")
{
 var containerName = container.HasProperty("containerTitle") && 
 container.HasValue("containerTitle")? container.GetPropertyValue
 ("containerTitle"): container.Name;
}
</pre>
```

please suggest your logics. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you mean. Would you be able to provide a tree structure to indicate what your existing structure is, what page you are doing this lookup on, and what page you wish to access?

Comment: Thanks for reply,  1) Homepage 1.a) Overview - subsite of Home page 2) About page. I need to display like "subsite page - parent site."

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure how these pages are nested. Is the about page on the same level as the home page?

Comment: Have you worked in Umbraco CMS if so How to create a navigation menu bar only display one's subsites alone other page wont.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your Umbraco content tree along with  a screenshot of the menu you would like to have displayed.?